# Cannot Add Acrobat PDF Control in Delphi XE3

Tags: pdf, activex, delphi-xe2, acrobat

I try to do as follows to add the Acrobat PDF control to my Delphi XE3 project, as follows:

1. In Delphi XE3, use "Import Component" -> "Import ActiveX Control", then select "Adobe Acrobat 7.0 Browser Control Type Library 1.0", it will generate AcroPDFLib_TLB.pas under Import directory.
2. Then I build and install the control, "TAcroPDF" will be installed under "ActiveX" panel successfully.
3. When I create a new form and move TAcroPDF to the form, I will get "Access Violation at address 6E009996 in module 'AcroPDF.dll'. Read of address 00000014" error message.
4. I click "Details" button and see the error details as follows:

[6E009996]{AcroPDF.dll} Unknown function at DllGetClassObject + $7D54
...
...

I have tried some more tests on this issue:

1. On my computer, there is also a Delphi 5 installed. So I do the same thing with Delphi 5. But everything is fine. The AcroPDF control can be added to the form and show PDF document without any problems.
2. I try to the same thing on another computer with Dephi XE3 installed, then everything is fine. I check the version of Delphi XE3 on two computers and they are the same. Both are XE3 version 17.0.4770.566661
3. I try to uninstall Acrobat Reader on the first computer. Then install the latest version of Acrobat Reader 11.0.8.4, the latest available version for Windows XP SP3. But still get the same error.

THanks

**Update**

Some more tests:

1. In the 2nd computer, if I debug the project, the PDF file can be loaded to the control successfully, via AcroPDF.LoadFile. However, when I exits the app, I will get the error message "access violation at 0x03251abd: read of address 0x03251abd'. If check the stack, it shows:

```
:03251abd
System._IntfClar(???)
:0040c763 @IntfClear + $13
System.Classes.TComponenet.DestroyComponenets
...
```

2. If I build the app in 2nd computer, then copy the exe to the 1st computer, then whenever I start the app, I will get  "Exception EAccessViolation in modeul AcroPDF.dll at 00009996. Access Violation at address 6E009996 in module 'AcroPDF.dll'. Read of address 00000014" error message.

Comment: Delphi 5 and Delphi XE3 may use different API because D5 uses ansi while XE3 uses Unicode.

Comment: The error makes me think it is a Acrobat issue which doesn't find a DLL or find a wrong version. You may use ProcessMonitor to spy on what DLL is really searched for and opened.

Comment: @fpiette, I have tried on another computer with XE3 and succeeds.

Comment: Does the executable compiled on that other computer run on the first? And what about the reverse: does the executable generated on the first computer (which doesn't work on that computer) runs well on the other computer?

Comment: @fpiette, I will try. Thank you for your advice.For the reverse, it is impossible as I cannot put the AcrobPDF control to the form, so not be able to build the EXE.

Comment: @fpiette, I have made some more tests based on your advice, which is put in the "Update" section of the question. Thank you very much. Also it seems that AcroPDF.dll is buggy. Is there any other PDF control provided by Adobe or other companies that works stablely?

Comment: I think you have different Acrobat Reader version on the two machines. If you look for software, try this: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=delphi+display+pdf+document

Comment: @fpiette, "I think you have different Acrobat Reader version on the two machines.". How you make such conclusion?

Comment: When you add a type library to Delphi, it uses the definition that is on the system you do the import. If then application using it works as expected on the system and do not work (I mean the binary executable), it means that on the second system, the type library is different, likely there is another, incompatible, version of the software. To confirm, you could compare the AcroPDFLib_TLB.pas generated by importing the type library in both systems.

Comment: @fpiette, I have compared two AcroPDFLib_TLB.pas and they are different.

Comment: This confirm two different Acrobat Reader. They are probably incompatibles in some way. This is frequent when software is updated but there is frequently a way to know the version at runtime and call the appropriate functions or use the appropriate structures. You have to read Adobe documentation to find that out.

Comment: @fpiette, Does that means the version used to created the control and .pas file must be same as the version when the application is running?

Comment: Depends on Acrobat developer choice. If he has done the right choice, you should import the OLDEST type library which should work with more recent Acrobat Reader program. The reverse is probably not working. This is how Microsoft does with his Office family: You can still use Office2000 type libraries (And Delphi components) with Office2019. Of course new 2019 features are not available but everything older still work. I hope Adobe has the same philosophy. Actually, I don't know...

Comment: Can I ask you, to add one more comment when you definitely solved this issue to tell if I was right or not?

Comment: @fpiette, Actually I have not solved the issue. What I do now is use Delphi 5 to build a small app, then use Delphi XE3 to invoke that app.

Comment: Have you tried to use the code generated by Delphi 5? It could require some change because Delphi 5 strings are Ansi while Delphi XE3 strings are Unicode. Try changing all string to ansistring in D5 code to make it work with Delphi XE3.

Comment: @fpiette, no, I have not done so as it will take too much time. I choose the simplest way to solve the issue.

Comment: I understand. You must understand that D5 is not a long term option.

Comment: @fpiette, thank you. Even with D5 app, when running on the 2nd computer, it can show the PDF, but when closing it, there will be an access violation error. The version of Acrobat Control should have a higher version that the 1st computer, since 2nd computer using Win 7 and the 1st using Win XP. On both I have tried to install the latest version of Acrobat Reader.

Comment: Sorry, I have no more idea.

Comment: @fpiette, no problem. You have already helped a lot. Thank you very much.